# How do I make a simple password page

Tags: html, web, passwords

(Beware, bad english)
I am trying to create a page wich just has a ''small block'' in where you can type a password wich I have set.

If you typed in the right password and press the ''Enter site'' button you will get send to the next page.

This doesn't have to be a fully protected website just a 1line form that sends you to a in the html code specified page if the typed in password is right.

I am a first year student on my school and really enjoying workin with html but since I am kind off far ahead of the rest of the class I would like to learn more, so I hope that there is someone who can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

[Here is an example I made in photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrDZp.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML alone can't do this you need some other language in backend to check password. Or you can use javascript which will verify password in frontend but you have to specify password in the code itself only if you are doing it for fun. Otherwise for developing web app with login page you need a backend language such as php or python and database such as mysql or mariadb to store passwords.

*Sample code*
You need to create two files one for your login form (login.html) and another to redirect after right password is entered (welcome.html).

This code is for login.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="pswd">Enter your password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="pswd">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkPswd();" />
</form>
<!--Function to check password the already set password is admin-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPswd() {
        var confirmPassword = "admin";
        var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
        if (password == confirmPassword) {
             window.location="welcome.html";
        }
        else{
            alert("Passwords do not match.");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is for welcome.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome!! you entered a right password</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not trying to make some kind of account database as you mentioned but I just want to set a password in for example js that when its typed into a text box and than submitted will send the website user to a specified page.

Comment: Hope this will work fine if I have not misunderstood you.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats what I was looking for.

Comment: This is kind off what is looks like right now. (Couldn't use the actual font on jsfiddle)https://jsfiddle.net/kaymeer/ocp8vg83/2/

Comment: Isn't this wildly laughably insecure, even for a joke page?