# Is there a way to make a passcode element before being able to view an HTML5 website?

Tags: javascript, html

**I want to add some sort of secret password to my website that the client would have to enter in order to access the site so that only my friends can view it.**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have access to server-side just use HTTP authentication

1. [Apache2 web server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html)
2. [Nginx web server](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/)

I suggest using Digest type for better security.

and if you don't have access to server-side
you can encrypt your content and use javascript to decrypt it with a specific password
so, you need an encryption algorithm

I suggest AES-CBC for better security.

you can find some example here 
[js SubtleCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt)

first, encrypt your data with your password

then put encrypted text in somewhere

and then ask the user for key

try to decrypt text by key and show data

you are done (:

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that on the client side. The code will be visible if you do inspect element. You need to do this server side only to really make it secure.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very broad question, and there is no one answer, but you can't just do it with regular HTML, you need to use the server side in order to do that. I don't know what your skill set is, but I'd suggest looking at

this stack overflow question: [How do I make a simple password page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180103/how-do-i-make-a-simple-password-page)

or this article: [How to Password Protect a Page or Directory on Your Site](https://www.freelancer.com/community/articles/how-to-password-protect-a-page-directory)

**EDIT**

You can do it with the client side, using JS but it's **not recommended**.